# Firebase - 2FA login with twilio

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, twilio, two-factor-authentication

#### Background

My web app stores medical info, so therefore requires users to verify their phone numbers and use a compulsory 2FA system every time they login, which I am using Twilio for. After a user signs in with their email and password they are taken to a screen where they have to enter their 6 digit one time which was sent to their phone upon signing in.

#### My Problem

Immediately after a user signs in, they have full access to their data. If a malicious user gained someone's email and password, they could completely bypass the 2FA step, defeating its purpose.

How can I make sure that users signing in complete the 2FA process? Even better, how can I write firestore security rules to only allow a 2 factor authenticated user to access their own data?

#### My Attempt

I thought I could write a session ID to firestore under a user document in a users collection when they log in (before 2FA) and then when they verify their 6 digit code, a cloud function marks the user as 2FA verified. This verification mark could be used in firestore rules, but the problem is that firebase auth ID tokens only last 1 hour, so the session ID stored in firestore would be invalidated, causing a user to have to reauthenticate every hour, much shorter than the 2FA verification should last.

Comment: GCIP (advanced version of Firebase Auth) supports [2FA with SMS](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa) and is compatible with other Firebase services. Have you considered using that?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have exactly the same